# Different security.yml files for different environments

Tags: php, symfony

I could not manage to find a way to include different `security.yml` files that would be included depending on Symfony2`s environment. For example I wanted to have an in-memory user provider for my acceptance tests, cause I don't really need to test my entities and stuff here, I only want to make an acceptance test for my views.

But, as it turned out, it's not an easy thing to do. I removed `security.yml` from includes in my `config.yml`, renamed it to `security_prod.yml` and created a `security_test.yml` which has the `in_memory` user provider. Then I've included `security_prod.yml` and `security_test.yml` in my production and testing configs respectively.

Yet it does not seem to work at all:

```
$ SYMFONY_ENV=test app/console cache:clear                                                      

  [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]                                                           
  You are not allowed to define new elements for path "security.providers". Please define all elements for this path in one config file.  

$ SYMFONY_ENV=prod app/console cache:clear                                                      

  [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\ForbiddenOverwriteException]                                                                         
  Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten. You have to define all options for this path, and any of its sub-paths in one   
  configuration section.
```

It appeared to me like the `security.yml` filename was hardcoded (which would be way too weird for Symfony), and it wasn't.

So the question is: how do I get multiple `security.yml`s with Symfony? And what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Can you post your config.yml config_prod.yml and config_test.yml (or at least the parts where the files are included)?

Comment: @CarlosGranados, thanks for your concern, but it turned out the problem was found sitting in my office chair. I was including my security.ymls twice :)

Comment: That is what I suspected, and that is why I asked you to post those files

Comment: @Brad Larson: Quite contrary, this question is very likely to help many future visitors because it deals with subject which has a very slim documentation. That is Unit/Functional tests in Symfony, and It would be very useful to have working example of security configurations for different environments.

Comment: @ĐuroMandinić - I was asked to close it because it had been resolved due to an apparently unrelated issue in the above comments. If that's not the case, I'll reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instruction for those, who is looking for it (and do not red comments):

1. Create different `config` files for different environments: `config_test.yml`, `config_dev.yml`, `config_prod.yml`
2. Create different `security` files: `security_test.yml`, `security_dev.yml`, `security_prod.yml`
3. Import  `security_test.yml` in `config_test.yml` and so on for other environments. Example for `config_test.yml`:

   ```
   imports:
     - { resource: security_test.yml }
   ```
4. Make sure you included `security_*.yml` only once (basically author did this mistake)